# replace a set of strings in one file on multiple lines based on a set of characters on a single line in another file

Tags: regex, bash, binary, str-replace

I have an xml *file1* with multiple "true" or "false" parameters on different lines.

I have another *file2* with a list of binary values.

Preferably using bash, I want to replace these true/false parameters based on the individual bits of those values, while being able to locate those parameters in file1 since there are other segments of that file that need to be untouched.

Ultimately, I need to have this work on OSX, however if someone can provide a solution in CentOS, Ubuntu, or FreeBSD, I'm confident I can translate for myself from there.

For example -
*file1*:

```
    <parameter>
        true
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        true
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        true
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        true
    </parameter>
```

*file2*:

```
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

So, I'm looking for a way so that I can grab the value on a *specific line* of *file2* and translate those into true/false values. So that I could grab the value from line 2 (1001) and that would translate to the following in *file1*:

```
    <parameter>
        true
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        false
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        false
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        true
    </parameter>
```

`for i in $(sed -n '13p' < test.binary | awk -F '' -v 'OFS=\n' '{$1=$1}1'); do echo $i`

This gets the values that I want to translate (1s and 0s on separate lines). After this I'm not sure how to map those values to the xml file and use them to update true/false values, sequentially.

For every line of that output, I need to figure out what will map those values to a range of lines in the xml file by finding the first instance of "true" or "false" and change/ignore it based on whether the source value is a 1 or a 0.

Here is a segment of the structure I'm trying to edit, output with cat -n. The file is about 342 lines long and the values I'm trying to update are every 3rd line starting on 237 and ending on 333.

Assuming an output from the original binary file of:

```
1
0
1
```

I'm looking for something that will achieve (assuming the following range of lines is set):

```
245             <Value property="forced4"  type="boolean" > 
246                 true  ###1, so unchanged 
247             </Value> 
248             <Value property="forced5"  type="boolean" > 
249                 false ###0, so unchanged
250             </Value> 
251             <Value property="forced6"  type="boolean" > 
252                 false ###1, updated to 'true'
253             </Value>
```

I would need something that would map line 1 to line 246, line 2 to line 249, line 3 to line 252, and so on, and then compare the values between them and either translate 1=true,0=false or have that already done. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried various for loops, combinations of sed, tr, awk, etc. If at all possible I'd prefer to use bash, but I have perl available to me (I'm just not very good at it).

Comment: *"`there are other segments of that file [file1?] that need to be untouched`"* Then you have to show the whole structure of `file1`. Otherwise we cannot *"`locate those parameters in file1`"*.

Comment: Also, is there anything you tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: `for i in $(sed -n '13p' < test.binary | awk -F '' -v 'OFS=\n' '{$1=$1}1'); do echo $i` 
This gets the values that I want to translate (1s and 0s on separate lines). After this I'm not sure how to map those values to the xml file and use them to update true/false values, sequentially.

Comment: Here is a segment of the structure I'm trying to edit, output with `cat -n`. The file is about 342 lines long and the values I'm trying to update are every 3rd line starting on 237 and ending on 333.
 
`245             <Value property="forced4"  type="boolean" >
246                 true 247             </Value>
248             <Value property="forced5"  type="boolean" >
249                 false
250             </Value>
251             <Value property="forced6"  type="boolean" >
252                 false
253             </Value>`

Comment: You can edit your question. Please click the small grey text `edit` left below your question and incorporate this information into your question.

Comment: Updated, sorry I'm still getting the hang of writing good and complete questions, sometimes my own process is hard to follow sort of just pasting my (embarassing) bash history. 
Another thing I've attempted is direct command substitution in a loop with the variable replacing parameters via sed, but this seems to fail for a syntax reason I'm not quite understanding.